# Symfony: _csrf_token [Required.]

Tags: php, symfony

I created an admin page using symfony generate-admin and for some reason I'm getting that error when trying to delete a record. Do you know why that field is not being generated?

I found the generated templates in the cache directory and I can see there is a call to $form->isCSRFProtected() to check whether or not to add the _csrf_token field. That function is returning false but I can't find where to change that.

I fixed it temporarily buy disabling the CSRF validation in actions.php. It's not ideal but it works in the meantime.

Comment: does the twig template contain a form_rest() call? That's what generates the CSRF hidden input for forms. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did not create a template for that page, it is automatically generated (I think). The other admin pages I created are working just fine.

Comment: Does the automatically generated template contain a form_rest() call?

Comment: I know this page is generated; but knowing if form_rest() is within the page should narrow down the source of your problem.

Comment: I checked the generated templates in the cache directory and I don't see any calls to form_rest(). I added more info to the original question.